# Can I obfuscate a compiled .NET executable/assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation, eazfuscator

So I'm trying to obfuscate my program AFTER it's been compiled. I'm pretty sure that's how you do it (?)

I'm using a pretty popular freeware called EazFuscator which has a nice little command line utility.

So if I go:

```
Eazfuscator.NET MyProgram.exe
```

it'll obfuscate it successfully, and when it's done, I'll try to run my program and it crashes! (gives me some runtime exception)

Another thing I tried instead is to obfuscate one of the DLL's my program uses:

```
EazFuscator.NET SomeDLLMyProgramUses.dll
```

it'll obfuscate it successfully, but again, when I run my program crashes...

I'm wondering first off, regardless of this EazFuscator program, is it possible to obfuscate .DLL and .EXE files? and is it usually NOT supposed to break them?

Note: I do have some reflection going on in my program, and maybe that's whats causing the problem.. but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Obfuscate the executable and dll as one logical unit. This will ensure any references from the executable to the dll remain consistent after renaming all symbols. I'm not sure Eazfuscator has that capability, you might want to look at another obfuscator named [Agile.net Code Protection](http://www.secureteam.net)

Answer (score 6):

There is [Dotfuscator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227240.aspx) community edition, which you could try.

In general obfuscators are not supposed to break the apps they obfuscate.  You should contact the manufacturer if you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the Obfuscation tools have settings that allow you to manage the level of obfuscation - like type names, method names, strings and so on. It is possible that your level of obfuscation has resulted in an IL code that is broken due to these changes that the tool performed on your original IL code. Check the settings available and attempt to avoid a few of those settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using reflection then the obfuscation tool will probably break you code.  During obfuscation type names are usually changed, therefore your reflection may not work as expected, especially if you are referring to a type by name.  Use a tool like [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to have a look at you obfuscated assembly, you will be able to see whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we need to obfuscate our assembly after compilation. Assembly is built again by obfuscator. So we don't need to worry about compilation and building it.

I am using FxProtect which is free obfuscator. Advance Professional version is also available but it is not free. You can try it...

[**.Net Obfuscator**](http://www.maycoms.net)

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not typically obsfucate your executable program. I'm sure you've been thinking about it since you posted your question and can imagine why.

Run the obfuscation on your source code then compile that into deliverable.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not your code is broken by obfuscation depends upon what you do in your code. If you're using reflection in there that will almost certainly be the root cause.

[CLISecure](http://www.secureteam.net/index.aspx) has worked well for me in the past (even on mixed-mode assemblies) ...but we don't use any reflection in our codebase.