# How to make .Net project practically unreadable

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I was wondering, if i ever make a program that i want to publish(perhaps a game), and i want to protect the code, how do i make it unreadable?

i am a student, and on my course i learn c#, i use ILSPY to see how others program games and such, but at some point it looked not like normal code, i am sure that a program had changed all the names of functions/variables/constants enz.
i took a screenshot:[image: EncryptedCode]
i have tried to find software that can do this, but i found it to be quite hard to find anything on the subject,
if you could help me by giving me the name of a program or plugin for VS2010 that is capable of something like this,

Thank you for reading my question

Comment: The term you're looking for is obfuscation.  If you search for that it will reveal a host of tools for obfuscating your .Net code

Comment: What you're looking for is called an obfuscator.

Comment: You can obfuscate but it won't protect you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I obfuscate a compiled .NET executable/assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491174/can-i-obfuscate-a-compiled-net-executable-assembly)

Comment: What you are looking for is `obfuscation`, have a look at http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview

Comment: http://confuser.codeplex.com/

Comment: [Best .NET obfuscation tools/strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2525), [Free obfuscation tools for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/805549) But like others have said, it's worthless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called Obfuscation, and VS comes with Dotfuscator (it's under the Tools menu) that does basic obfuscation of type and member names, though a skilled RCE can figure it out.

More powerful obfuscation tools exist that rewrite the CIL to defeat analysis by tools like Reflector, though hardcore RCE folks can read and divine CIL directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a technique called obfuscation. If you search for a C# Obfuscator, you can find numerous examples of both free and quite expensive ones.

one such list is here: http://www.csharp411.com/net-obfuscators/

Comment: this list is pathetically outdated

Answer (score 0):

It's called Obfuscation.  VS has a built in tool to handle this.  However it is not very effective.  There are paid versions that are much more effective.  Such as:

- http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm
- http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator

A more complete list can be found here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988451/net-obfuscation

Comment: No; VS does not have a built-in tool.  Some versions of VS include a free edition of a third-party tool.

Comment: @SLaks I thought every version of VS came with .Net Obfuscator Community Edition.